# Seat Map Layout using Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a problem in creating theatre seat map layout using Flutter. I need the seat arrangement to be scrollable, selectable.

[image]

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried, what is causing you the problem, and include some sample code.

Comment: I need the same UI layout in flutter. Can we do that?

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can consider to build a seat map layout is using the combination of [`Row`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) and [`Column`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) and a styled button to represent a seat.

You can make any Widget scrollable by wrapping it in a [`SingleChildScrolLView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html).

See also: [Flutter seat view with Column and Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957668/flutter-seat-view-with-column-and-row?rq=1)