# Flutter seat view with Column and Row

Tags: flutter

I'm newbie with Flutter. I'd like to build the train seats view using Row and Column. But I couldn't. 
Also this view must be scrollable. I tried Table widget but it is not scrollable for flutter.

Row and column count comes from api as dynamically. I tried to build view statically like below but i need to dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htgr1.png)

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("")),
                    Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("1")),
                    Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("2")),
                    Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("3")),
                    Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("4")),
                  ]
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("A")),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("00");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("00"))),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("01");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("01"))),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("02");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("02"))),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("03");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("03")))
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("B")),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("10");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("10"))),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("11");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("11"))),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("12");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("12"))),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("13");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("13"))),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("C")),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("20");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("20"))),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("21");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("21"))),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("22");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("22"))),
                    InkWell(onTap: () {print("23");},child:Container(height: 40, width: 40,child: Text("23"))),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: I need to build view that above dynamically. I mean there is column and row count comes from the api. I should build a seat view by that values @Eiko

Answer (score 0):

You can make any Widget scrollable by wrapping it in a SingleChildScrolLView. So if the Table Widget works for you, give that a try!

As is said, anything can be made scrollable this way. So you could make a Container that fits your entire screen, wrap it with a SingleChildScrolLView, and then put whatever you want in it.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

Comment: i've already used SingleChildScrollView. My problem is build seat view dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You have to Use `Listview.generate` along with a `ScrollView` to add the seats dynamically, into row and columns.

1. Create a Widget that will represent the `Seat`.
2. Suppose you have 10 items from api.Then use `GridView.count` to automatically generate the columns for you.

---

### Example

```
child: GridView.count(
   crossAxisCount:5,
   children: Listview.generate(10,(index){
       return Seat(
         id:json_response["items"][index]["id"]
         booked:false,
      );
    }
  ),
)
```